# Link to "help us create it" on tag info page is barely visible on Beta Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, beta-sites, accessibility

The tag info page of a tag without a wiki and an excerpt has a request in place of the excerpt, of the form:

> The [moderator-training](/questions/tagged/moderator-training) tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/256184)?

The link goes to the "Propose Tag Info" page for that particular tag. On Music Fans Meta, the colour scheme is such that [the link is barely visible](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topic-challenge), for instance:

> [image: Message for the [topic-challenge] tag on Music Fans Meta]

There, the link on "help us create it" has practically the same colour as the rest of the text. I have been editing the tag info for several tags on Music Fans Meta for quite a while and only now realised that there was a link directly to the edit page sitting there. Instead I've been navigating via "Learn More. . ." followed by "Propose Tag Info" every single time.

I presume that the current colour scheme is uniform across all Beta Meta sites. So, can the colour scheme for links on Beta Meta be changed so that they are more visible? This isn't the only link on Music Fans Meta, so I actually have no idea how many other useful links I may have missed.